# String concatenation in EL for dynamic ResourceBundle key

Tags: jsf, internationalization, el, string-concatenation, resourcebundle

I have a resource bundle with entries like these:

```
entry1=value1
entry2=value2
entry3=value3
```

In my JSF page I'm trying to use these keys dynamically. The ID of the entry is coming from a managed bean. I think it should be something like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['entry' managedBean.entryIndex]}"/>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you're already on Servlet 3.1 / EL 3.0 (Tomcat 8, WildFly 8, GlassFish 4, etc), make use of new EL 3.0 `+=` operator:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['entry' += managedBean.entryIndex]}" />
```

If you're only on Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 (Tomcat 7, JBoss AS 6/7, GlassFish 3, etc), make use of new EL 2.2 ability to directly invoke methods such as `String#concat()`:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['entry'.concat(managedBean.entryIndex)]}" />
```

If you're even not on Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 yet, make use of `<c:set>` to create another variable with the desired EL expression inlined:

```
<c:set var="key" value="entry#{managedBean.entryIndex}" />
<h:outputText value="#{msg[key]}" />
```

Comment: i hoped there is a one-line way for this, but this facelet-version is good enough. thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this is an EL restriction, not a JSF restriction. EL has no facilities for string concatenation inside an expression.

Answer (score 8):

This should solve your issue:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['entry'.concat(managedBean.entryIndex)]}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me : concat outside of []

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['entry'].concat(managedBean.entryIndex)}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to write a facelets function `concat(str1, str2)`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the hint, it works well with a facelet function.