# How to concatenate Strings in EL expression?

Tags: jsf, el, string-concatenation

I need to create a callback for `<h:commandButton>` while as a parameter I need to pass an argument that is string-concatenated with an external parameter id:

I tried nesting an EL expression something like this:

```
<h:commandButton ... action="#{someController.doSomething('#{id}SomeTableId')}" />
```

However this failed with an EL exception. What is a right syntax/approach to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you're already on EL 3.0 (Java EE 7; WildFly, Tomcat 8, GlassFish 4, etc), then you could use the new `+=` operator for this:

```
<h:commandButton ... action="#{someController.doSomething(id += 'SomeTableId')}" />
```

If you're however not on EL 3.0 yet, and the left hand is a genuine `java.lang.String` instance (and thus not e.g. `java.lang.Long`), then use EL 2.2 capability of invoking direct methods with arguments, which you then apply on `String#concat()`:

```
<h:commandButton ... action="#{someController.doSomething(id.concat('SomeTableId'))}" />
```

Or if you're not on EL 2.2 yet, then use JSTL `<c:set>` to create a new EL variable with the concatenated values just inlined in value:

```
<c:set var="tableId" value="#{id}SomeTableId" />
<h:commandButton ... action="#{someController.doSomething(tableId)}" />
```

#### See also:

- [String concatenation in EL for dynamic ResourceBundle key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852037/string-concatenation-in-el-for-dynamic-resourcebundle-key/)