# Escape JavaScript quotes in EL in a JSF component attribute

Tags: javascript, jsf, el, quotes

I have an onclick event that depends on the state of a variable. So I need to do something like

```
onclick="#{object.isEnabled ? 'ch.my.js_method('#{object.property}'); return false;' : 'return false;'"
```

The problem is, that I can't use `'` inside of the onclick. How can I escape the quotes inside of the EL?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: The question is sound, but you're using curly quotes instead of straight quotes. Is this also the case in real code? This only introduces a red herring in the question. Look closer at the code you just posted yourself here above. The difference between `‘` and `'` is pretty clear. Those double quotes around the attribute value are even invalid because those are curly instead of straight. Code usually only accepts straight quotes.

Comment: This is just an error in typing: in the source file I used straight quotes. However, it did not work...

Comment: Nope, no console errors but an error when parsing the xhtml

Answer (score 4):

You can escape them with `\` or `\\`, but rules differ per EL implementation, because it isn't clear cut in EL spec (Oracle's EL impl needs single backslash, but Apache needs double backslash). And you need the `+=` operator to string-concatenate the EL expression.

```
<x:someComponent onclick="#{object.isEnabled ? 'ch.my.js_method(\'' += object.property += '\'); return false;' : 'return false;'}" />
```

Safest bet is to just create an alias with help of `<c:set>`.

E.g.

```
<c:set var="js_method" value="ch.my.js_method('#{object.property}'); return false;" />
<x:someComponent onclick="#{object.isEnabled ? js_method : 'return false;'}" />
```

You've only still a potential problem if `#{object.property}` can contain JS-special characters which can in turn cause invalid JS output, such as single quotes or newlines. Head to the second link below for the solution to that.

#### See also:

- [How to concatenate Strings in EL expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680903/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-el-expression)
- [How do I pass JSF managed bean properties to a JavaScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709014/how-do-i-pass-jsf-managed-bean-properties-to-a-javascript-function/)

Comment: The escaping did not work. Error: `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`

Comment: Neither did the version with the alias. 

`SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression
...ch.my.js_method('343556'); return false; : 'return false;`

looks like the quotes around the onclick event are missing...

Comment: I just forgot a `}`. Answer has been fixed. Sorry for that. Just blame Stack Overflow for not having a compiler and syntax checker built into the message editor :)

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution: just invert the condition and add the event afterwards. This way the quotes around the JS method are not needed:

`onclick="#{object.isEnabled == 'false' ? 'return false;' : ''} ch.my.js_method('#{object.property}'); return false;"`