# Using .properties inside EL expressions

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I have a datatable with a column button that fires a dialog modal and a .properties file with the various id's of the application pages.

Column example:

```
<p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
         <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" headerText="Detail" update=":form_datatable:dialog_datatable" oncomplete="PF('dialog_datatable').show()">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row}" target="#{testBean.selectedRow}" />
         </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

Propierties:

```
application.table.dialog=dialog_datatable
```

I just want to avoid hardcoding the **oncomplete="PF('dialog_datatable').show()"** and use .propierties inside of the EL expresion. There is any posible way?

Like: oncomplete="PF(#{app.['application.table.detail']}).show()"

EDIT: @BalusC Isn't the same type of question, the other one is using a var="" inside the same xhtml datatable, im trying to use a .propierties file to don't hardcode id/widgetVar.

EDIT2: After some research in my free time i finally found a way to do it, is better than hardcode it. (i don't know how i can answer my own question...)

```
    <ui:param name="var_dialog" value="#{app['application.table.dialog']}" />
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" update=":form_city:dialog_city" oncomplete="PF('#{var_dialog}').show()">
```

Comment: Two things wrong here... the . after app should not be there and the whole 'EL' part should be in single quotes (it should result in PF('id') and now it is PF(id). You need to escape the single quotes in the [ ]. And just try and see what errors you get.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, i tried to remove the quotes inside the [ ] resulting on this: oncomplete="PF(#{app.[application.table.detail]}).show()". The errors are: eclipse EL syntax error: Expecting Java method or property name. And browser: oncomplete="PF(#{app.[application.table.detail]}).show()" Failed to parse the expression [PF(#{app.[application.table.detail]}).show()]

Comment: No, I did not say remove the quotes in the [ ], I said **escape** (but this might not be needed after all) And you **did not** remove the . after app. And you **did not** put single quotes in side the ().... PLEASE read what I state. It should be `PF('#{app['application.table.detail']}')` or  `PF('#{app[\'application.table.detail\']}')` but I think the former might already do the trick

Comment: What are you tring to say with escape is: &apos; ? it results on this: oncomplete="PF('#{app[&apos;'application.table.detail&apos;]}').show()". The page load correctly but when i click the button browser fires the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Comment: Failed to parse the expression [PF('#{app[\'application.table.detail\']}').show()] it failed again... In eclipse the error is: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Syntax error in EL
 - EL syntax error: Expecting 
  expression.

Comment: @BalusC: The escaping of the 'key' with dots (.) in them is the related issue here... I cannot seem to find an explicit duplicate of that

Comment: tried `PF('#{app['application.table.detail']}')` to?

Comment: @Kukeltje: yes, i tried it, and nothing...

Comment: nothing what? Error? WW3?

Comment: @Kukeltje: This? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33019729

Comment: @BalusC: yes, thanks