# Dynamic resource bundle reference

Tags: jsf, internationalization, el, oracle-adf

I'm generating text inputs in an iterator from a collection I find in a managed bean.

How can I dynamically display the label with a resource bundle message I receive from this bean?

`<af:iterator id="i3" var="myVar" value="#{pageFlowScope.MyBean.myCollection}">
    <af:inputText id="it4" label="#{myVar.name}" value="#{myVar.value}"  />

</af:iterator>`

Here, `myVar.name` is a String representation of a key present in the bundle, like `button.label.field` or anything else.

Is it possible to pass this String as a parameter to my bundle reference?

Something like: `label="#{myBundle[ #{myVar.name} ]}"`?

I tried with `c:set` and with `ui:param` like proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852037/jsf-resourcebundle-key-concatenation) but it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been stupid, and finally found the answer... My resource bundle was empty (deleted it and then forgot to fill it again).

So this is the solution:

`<c:set var="nameKey" value="#{myVar.name}"/>
    <af:inputText id="it4" value="#{bc2Field.value}" label="#{helpdeskBundle[nameKey]}"/>`